# Cannot explicitly call operator or accessor on Event Handler

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to debug the code done by the previous SI.

```
    protected void VendorAccountMapping_ApAcctID_FieldUpdated(
      PXCache cache,
      PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        VendorAccountMapping row = (VendorAccountMapping)e.Row;
        Account account = PXResultset<Account>.op_Implicit(PXSelectBase<Account, PXSelect<Account, Where<Account.accountID, Equal<Required<Account.accountID>>>>.Config>.Select((PXGraph)this, new object[1]
        {
    (object) row.Apacctid
        }));
        if (account == null)
            return;
        row.Apacctcd = account.AccountCD;
        row.APAcctDesc = account.Description;
    }
```

The above code was salvaged from dll file but when I tried to replicate it in Visual Studio,  [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkfZX.png) was shown instead and the code couldn't be compiled.

What causes this error and how can I possibly fix it?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, the problem is the explicit call to `op_Implicit`, which is not allowed

Comment: I tried mending the code to `PXResultset<VendorAccountMapping> vendorAccountMapping = PXSelectBase<VendorAccountMapping, PXSelect<VendorAccountMapping, Where<VendorAccountMapping.vendorID, Equal<Required<VendorAccountMapping.vendorID>>, And<VendorAccountMapping.branchID, Equal<Required<VendorAccountMapping.branchID>>>>>.Config>.Select(Base, new object[2] {row.VendorID, row.BranchID});` but now the error changed to _'PXResultset..' does not contain a definition for 'Apacctid' and no accessible extension method 'Apacctid' accepting a first argument of type 'PXResultSet..' could be found_ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you try this simpler statement

```
 Account account = SelectFrom<Account>.Where<Account.accountID.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.View.Select(this,row.Apacctid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the simpler statement, Patrick. I will try to code it and see if it fixed the issues